# trying to use nohup but keep getting another windows to show up

Tags: nohup

i want to launch windows 10 from virtualbox and i'm created a shortcut to my desktop and click on proprieties to get the commend line to start windows 10 from a menu, so i put the command in the command line using nohup so the terminal will close after it starts but i keep getting another terminal open with the nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out' err how can i get rid of this windows from showing up?

Comment: Can you edit your question to contain the contents of the desktop shortcut? The file is named something like `~/Desktop/foo.desktop`.You probably just need to edit it to change `Terminal=true` to `Terminal=false`

Answer (score 0):

To get `nohup` to "shutup" *stdin*, *stdout* and *stderr* all need to be explicitly directed from/to somewhere. So you could do this:

```
nohup cmd </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1
```

But a simpler solution is to just redirect *stderr* since that's where the warning is coming from:

```
nohup cmd 2>/dev/null
```

Now I don't know if this will prevent the window from popping but it's a place to start. Try the short version. If that doesn't work try the first version. If neither work then we'll at least know a little more than we do now.